# Enum containing Enum Java (enumCeption)

Tags: java, enums

How to pass enum in enum constructor ?
Here is what I tried so far.

This is to guarantee that I don't mix up pages and their respective sections.
I would like to be able to do 'SectionsEnum section = PAGE2.sectionsEnum.SECTION_D;' somewhere else in my code.

PagesEnum.class

```
public enum PagesEnum {
  PAGE1(Page1Sections.class), // incompatible types, required SectionsEnum found Page1Sections
  PAGE2(Page2Sections.class);

  Class<? extends SectionsEnum> sectionsEnum;  

  PagesEnum(final Class<? extends SectionsEnum> sectionsEnum) {
    this.sectionsEnum = sectionsEnum;
  }
}
```

Page1Sections.enum

```
public enum Page1Sections implements SectionsEnum {
  SECTION_A,
  SECTION_B;
}
```

Page2Sections.enum

```
public enum Page2Sections implements SectionsEnum {
  SECTION_C,
  SECTION_D;
}
```

Main.class

```
public class Main {
    public void example() {
        SectionsEnum section = PAGE2.sectionsEnum.SECTION_D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Class<? extends SectionsEnum>`

Comment: I don't see how you could achieve `PAGE2.SECTION_D` by passing an enum class in the constructor.

Comment: This will make your code compile. But you cannot achieve something like `PAGE2.SECTION_D`

Answer (score 0):

you can never get PAGE2.SECTION_D but you can do the relation other way around SECTION_D.getPage():
:

```
public enum SectionsEnum {
  SECTION_A(PagesEnum.PAGE1),
  SECTION_B(PagesEnum.PAGE1),
  SECTION_C(PagesEnum.PAGE2),
  SECTION_D(PagesEnum.PAGE2),
  ;
PagesEnum(PagesEnum page) {...}
}
```

Comment: This won't give you `PAGE2.SECTION_D`.

Comment: you can never get PAGE2.SECTION_D (edited answer to make it more clear)